# Displaying images stored on Amazon S3 using Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, heroku, carrierwave

I am trying to upload images and then display them in my app

I configure the app on Heroku to upload files to Amazon S3. I am able to upload the images to S3. I can see it at Amazon. However i am not able to display it.

I used the code:

```
<%= image_tag user.profile_image.avatar.url, :size => "80x80" %>
```

It generates the following HTML (i change img to imgtag since stackoverflow would not allow me to add this code):

```
<imgtag alt="Bob_dylanplanetwaves" height="80" src="http://appname-heroku/uploads/profile_image/avatar/1/bob_dylanplanetwaves.jpg"; width="80" />
```

http://appname-heroku/uploads/profile_image/avatar/1/bob_dylanplanetwaves.jpg doe not point to any valid image.

I tried the following with no success:

```
<%= image_tag user.profile_image.avatar.current_path, :size => "80x80" %>.
```

it generated this code:

```
<imgtag alt="Album-the-bootleg-series-vol-4-bob-dylan-live-1966-the-royal-albert-hall-concert" height="80" src="/images/uploads/profile_image/avatar/2/album-the-bootleg-series-vol-4-bob-dylan-live-1966-the-royal-albert-hall-concert.jpg" width="80" />
```

In both cases the images are not displayed

I am using CarrierWave to uplaod the file
Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.3 and hosting at Heroku

Comment: Are you using the PaperClip gem? (edit - Sorry, didn't see you said CarrierWave)

Comment: Ah, your code is a mess. I cleaned it up but please try to post it so people can read it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your url should look:

```
src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_appname/amazon_bucket_name/pictures/large/20.jpg"
```

`appname`: the name of your application in your apps which you can check in your heroku profile. `amazon_bucket_name`: this needs to be the name of the bucked you created on AS3.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it with no success. With a little more research the following worked. http://amazon_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com//pictures/large/20.jpg 
I thought Heroku would create this URL for me

Comment: no, like @mason suggested if you use paperclip it will create the url automatically for you.

Comment: i was never able to get PaperClip to work for me. failed to install ImageMagic on my window machine :-(

Comment: Are you using windows? If you have a mac use macpors.

Comment: the app name does not get written into the URL - it's simply http://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon_bucket_name/....

Comment: @john Beynon you forgot to add the heroku app name to the url

Comment: why does the heroku app name get involved buckets are accessed via http://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon_bucket_name irrespective of the heroku app name - unless this is something super specific to Paperclip?

Comment: I really don't know but all my apps have the app name in the url. Might be something specific for my apps but I've seen it other places too.